# Get the text of a button widget

Tags: python, button, tkinter, widget

I want to get the text from a button to compare it using an if-statement.

Say I have this button:

```
my_button = Button(self, text = 'hi')
my_button.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
```

And want to do something like this:

```
my_text = my_button.text
```

So that the following if-statement evaluates as True:

```
if my_text == 'hi':
    # do something
```

How can I do this in an easy way?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
my_text = my_button['text']
```

Tkinter allows you to access any option of a widget this way (`height`, `width`, `text`, etc.)

---

If you need this as a method call, you can use [`.cget`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.cget-method):

```
my_text = my_button.cget('text')
```

Note that this method is available on all standard Tkinter widgets.

Comment: Brilliant. So it was as simple as that. Thank you kind sir, this helps a lot.

Comment: You might want to also mention the `cget` method.

Comment: @Bryan: Had not heard of that method either. Good idea. Thanks for both answers. Easy and clear.

Comment: This does not appear to work on TTK Button.