# tkinter access button config information

Tags: python, button, tkinter, config, return-value

I am writing a code that will enable me to control the hue lights in my house using the phue library from GitHub. I am using Tkinter as the GUI and I need to assign each room to a button and to an "ON" button. To do that, I need to somehow access text variables that I have assigned to every room's button. I'd imagine it would be something like this:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
button = Button(root, text = "room 1")
button.pack()
print(button.config(text)) #this should return "room 1"
root.mainloop()
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the text of a button widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26765218/get-the-text-of-a-button-widget)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: `print(button['text'])`

Long Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26765236/7522901

Comment: Thank you so much! It did exactly what I wanted it to.