# How can I check if Entry widget is Disabled?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
    from tkinter import *
    win = Tk()
    win.geometry("195x390+50+250")
    e = Entry(win,state=DISABLED,borderwidth=3)
def fun():
        if e.configure(state=DISABLED):
            e.configure(state=NORMAL)
        else:
            e.configure(state=DISABLED)
    b_fun=Button(win, text="fun",padx=25,pady=20,command=fun)
    win.mainloop()
```

I want to make button which checks if Entry state is Disabled and if it is I want to make Entry Normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here, the question and the first answer : [Get the text of a button widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26765218/get-the-text-of-a-button-widget)
Now I think you can do the same with entry widgets, because the guy says "Tkinter allows you to access any option of a widget this way" ;)