# tkinter button reffer self atribute

Tags: python, tkinter, button, attributes

A have a Grid of 38 buttons (num0-num38).
I'm trying to pass the button attribute (text) to the print function.

```
Code:
def collect_num(num):
    print(num)

num0 = tk.Button(buttons, text="0", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg="green", command=collect_num(thisItem.text))
```

Is there something similar to thisItem.text in Python?
So basically, I would like to print the button name (text="0" - text="38") when the correspondent button is pressed.

Any help with that is appreciated.

Comment: Try: `command=lambda: collect_num(num0.cget('text')` and so on for each button.

Comment: Many thank for reply,
in that case I would need to refer all my bottoms with 
num0.cget('text')
num1.cget('text')
num2.cget('text')

etc.
for 38 buttons is no problem, but potentially I would like to have hundreds of them. 
Is there a way to use something more uni-formal like:
ThisItem.cget('text')

Comment: What you should have done is not make 100s of button like that, its very naïve, you should instead loop and make buttons, I could give you an example if you like.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you can give an example on how to loop and create buttons.
Sorry, for me being naive I don't have a significant coding experience ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked for an example, take a look here:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
MAX_BUTTON = 25 # Maximum number of buttons to be made

def collect_num(num):
    print(num) # Print the number

btns = [] # A list to add all the buttons, to make them reusable later
for i in range(MAX_BUTTON): # Looping 25 times or maximum number of buttons, times
    btns.append(Button(root,text=i,width=10))  # Creating a button and adding it to list
    btns[-1]['command'] = lambda x=btns[-1].cget('text'): collect_num(x) # Changing the command of the button
    btns[-1].pack() # Packing it on

root.mainloop()
```

Here `cget()` returns the current properties of the widget.

It is highly recommended to do this, instead of creating buttons one by one manually. There is a principle in software engineering called DRY which means Don't Repeat Yourself, which usually means if your repeating yourself, there will possibly be a way to not repeat your self and reduce the code written. And this looping and creating a widget and using `lambda` to make the `command` is quiet used frequently when needed to make more than one widget with a pattern.

Comment: Wow thank you a lot! This is much more elegant and exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

you need pass the button text using `partial(<function>, *args)` function

```
from functools import partial

def collect_num(num):
    print(num)

# create the button first and add some specs like `text`
button = tk.Button(
  buttons, text="0", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg="green"
)

# add command after creation with the above function and button's name
button.config(command=partial(collect_num, button["text"]))
```

with the help of this [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26765218/get-the-text-of-a-button-widget):

```
text = button["text"]
```

this is the method with which you can get the text.

or

```
text = button.cget('text')
```

or (with the help of @TheLizzard)

```
text = button.config("text")[-1]
```

Comment: just for completeness: `text = button.config("text")[-1]`

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for your reply I manage to make it work,
but looks like I'm using a bad/naive approach to create buttons ^^

Comment: my pleasure to help.