# How do I make loops in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I'm trying to make a memory game in tkinter, but I'm having trouble with some stuff. The buttons are working alright, but I can't figure out how to do the rest. I've created a bunch of buttons, **shuffled the strings so it is randomized**, but I don't understand 3 things:

1. How can I make "if" functions in tkinter?
2. How can I make the program understand the strings that are in the buttons, so it'll detect if the numbers in the buttons are correct?
3. How can I make the program detect that the user pressed 2 buttons?

Heres the code, so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import shuffle
from tkinter import ttk
# -------------------------------------------- CONFIGURATION --------------------------------------------
app=Tk()
app.title("Dan's project")
app.geometry("500x483")
numlist=[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6]
shuffle(numlist)
# -------------------------------------------- BUTTONS --------------------------------------------
def btn1clk():
    btn1.configure(bg = "grey", width=17,height=10, text = numlist[0])
btn1 = Button(app, text="Click Me!", bg="green", fg="black", width=17,height=10, command=btn1clk)
btn1.place(x=0, y=0)

def btn2clk():
    btn2.configure(bg = "grey", width=17,height=10, text = numlist[1])
btn2 = Button(app, text="Click Me!", bg="green", fg="black", width=17,height=10, command=btn2clk)
btn2.place(x=130, y=0)

def btn3clk():
    btn3.configure(bg = "grey", width=17,height=10, text = numlist[2])
btn3 = Button(app, text="Click Me!", bg="green", fg="black", width=17,height=10, command=btn3clk)
btn3.place(x=260, y=0)

def btn4clk():
    btn4.configure(bg = "grey", width=17,height=10, text = numlist[3])
btn4 = Button(app, text="Click Me!", bg="green", fg="black", width=17,height=10, command=btn4clk)
btn4.place(x=390, y=0)

def btn5clk():
    btn5.configure(bg = "grey", width=17,height=10, text = numlist[4])
btn5 = Button(app, text="Click Me!", bg="green", fg="black", width=17,height=10, command=btn5clk)
btn5.place(x=0, y=160)

def btn6clk():
    btn6.configure(bg = "grey", width=17,height=10, text = numlist[5])
btn6 = Button(app, text="Click Me!", bg="green", fg="black", width=17,height=10, command=btn6clk)
btn6.place(x=130, y=160)

def btn7clk():
    btn7.configure(bg = "grey", width=17,height=10, text = numlist[6])
btn7 = Button(app, text="Click Me!", bg="green", fg="black", width=17,height=10, command=btn7clk)
btn7.place(x=260, y=160)

def btn8clk():
    btn8.configure(bg = "grey", width=17,height=10, text = numlist[7])
btn8 = Button(app, text="Click Me!", bg="green", fg="black", width=17,height=10, command=btn8clk)
btn8.place(x=390, y=160)

def btn9clk():
    btn9.configure(bg = "grey", width=17,height=10, text = numlist[8])
btn9 = Button(app, text="Click Me!", bg="green", fg="black", width=17,height=10, command=btn9clk)
btn9.place(x=0, y=320)

def btn10clk():
    btn10.configure(bg = "grey", width=17,height=10, text = numlist[9])
btn10 = Button(app, text="Click Me!", bg="green", fg="black", width=17,height=10, command=btn10clk)
btn10.place(x=130, y=320)

def btn11clk():
    btn11.configure(bg = "grey", width=17,height=10, text = numlist[10])
btn11 = Button(app, text="Click Me!", bg="green", fg="black", width=17,height=10, command=btn11clk)
btn11.place(x=260, y=320)

def btn12clk():
    btn12.configure(bg = "grey", width=17,height=10, text = numlist[11])
btn12 = Button(app, text="Click Me!", bg="green", fg="black", width=17,height=10, command=btn12clk)
btn12.place(x=390, y=320)

app.mainloop()
```

***thanks in advance!***

Comment: It is not a good idea to include several questions in one post as you will get partial answers and your question might be closed as "Need more focus" (see the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions))

Comment: kinda new to this site, thank you for clearing that one out!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a global variable that can know if user clicked 2 buttons

```
from tkinter import *
from random import shuffle
from tkinter import ttk
# -------------------------------------------- CONFIGURATION --------------------------------------------
app=Tk()
app.title("Dan's project")
app.geometry("500x483")
numlist=[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6]
shuffle(numlist)
detect= 1
# -------------------------------------------- BUTTONS --------------------------------------------
def btn1clk():
    global detect
    if detect >= 2:
        print('pressed 2 buttons')
    detect +=1
    btn1.configure(bg = "grey", width=17,height=10, text = numlist[0])
btn1 = Button(app, text="Click Me!", bg="green", fg="black", width=17,height=10, command=btn1clk)
btn1.place(x=0, y=0)

def btn2clk():
    global detect
    if detect >= 2:
        print('pressed 2 buttons')
    detect +=1
    btn2.configure(bg = "grey", width=17,height=10, text = numlist[1])
btn2 = Button(app, text="Click Me!", bg="green", fg="black", width=17,height=10, command=btn2clk)
btn2.place(x=130, y=0)

def btn3clk():
    global detect
    if detect >= 2:
        print('pressed 2 buttons')
    detect +=1
    btn3.configure(bg = "grey", width=17,height=10, text = numlist[2])
btn3 = Button(app, text="Click Me!", bg="green", fg="black", width=17,height=10, command=btn3clk)
btn3.place(x=260, y=0)

def btn4clk():
    global detect
    if detect >= 2:
        print('pressed 2 buttons')
    detect +=1
    btn4.configure(bg = "grey", width=17,height=10, text = numlist[3])
btn4 = Button(app, text="Click Me!", bg="green", fg="black", width=17,height=10, command=btn4clk)
btn4.place(x=390, y=0)

def btn5clk():
    global detect
    if detect >= 2:
        print('pressed 2 buttons')
    detect +=1
    btn5.configure(bg = "grey", width=17,height=10, text = numlist[4])
btn5 = Button(app, text="Click Me!", bg="green", fg="black", width=17,height=10, command=btn5clk)
btn5.place(x=0, y=160)
app.mainloop()
```

EDIT: If you want to check the text of the button, you can use (button_name)['text']. Example:

```
def btn1clk():
    global detect
    if detect >= 2:
        print('pressed 2 buttons')
    detect +=1
    btn1.configure(bg = "grey", width=17,height=10, text = numlist[0])
    # Here will print out btn1 text
    print(btn1['text'])
```

More info about button text [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26765218/get-the-text-of-a-button-widget)

Comment: Why not use a list of buttons that is created in a for loop? It will shorten the code by quite a lot

Comment: @TheLizzard im sorry but i cannot do this in tkinter, because i've cancel it for a year :-(

Comment: Look at [this](https://pastebin.com/6ArG2J7T). It's the same as your code but it uses a for loop.

Comment: Oh that working properly, i'll research again this code, thanks.

Comment: tysm, do you know how to make it so it will detect the strings that are in the buttons? thanks again, i could do the rest

Comment: if you want to get the text of the button, just add `(button_name)['text']` and it will give you the button text.

Comment: hmm, that doesnt seem to work, mind to write a quick example? thanks again!

Comment: @MHP alternatively could use `<tk.Button>.cget('text')`, it will return the text value. also you should notify the OP if you make any changes to your answer, I don't think they get notified about edits on answers